# Entity Framework 4.1 Linq Contains and StartsWith

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am using Entity Framework Code First. I want to query entites from database against List objects. This works fine with contains, but how can I combine it with StartsWith?

This is my code:

```
List<string> values = new List<string>();
values.Add("A");
values.Add("B");
context.Customer.Where(c => values.Contains(c.Name)).ToList();
```

How can i query against all customers which starts with A or B?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should work in memory, but I am not sure if it could be translated into SQL by EF:

```
context.Customer.Where(c => values.Any(s => c.Name.StartsWith(s))).ToList();
```

Comment: fyi update sadly with ef core this gets evaluated locally

warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[20500]
      The LINQ expression 'where {from String text in __texts_0 where [d].Entry.StartsWith([text]) select [text] => Any()}' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.

Comment: @AnthonyJohnston [This may be related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44372562/335858)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to combine it with StartsWith, since if it starts with A or B, then it obviously contains A or B.  It can't start with A or B and not contain A or B.

So just use StartsWith instead of Contains.

```
context.Customer.Where(c => c.StartsWith("A") || c.StartsWith("B")).ToList();
```

Comment: I am not using String.Contains() but List.Contains(). Your solution works but is not dynamic. E.g. query against A-K.

Comment: @LuckyStrike - I would suggest that if you have such requirements, you include them in your question.  Otherwise you just waste everyones time by rejecting solutions they couldn't have known were not what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You might try combining the two functions this way:

```
IQueryable<Customer> result = (from C in context.Customerwhere C.Name.StartsWith("B") && values.Contains(C.Name));
```

Comment: You're missing a space in from C in `context.Customerwhere` it should be from C in `context.Customer where`